# Trying to design algo to generate MST in better than O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to design algo to beat O(n^2) where n is the number of vertices. Want to avoid dependency on "number of edges",as for a complete graph, m=n^2.

My attempts:
Tried Prims(has run time O(mlogn)), Kruskals(has run time O(mlogn));
Cant use Boruvka, as this does not handle distinct edges.

I think I can achive it by altering Prims/Kruskals, but cant seem to put my finger on it.

Some way, that i can remove dependency on "m"(number of edges)
Thanks in advance for any inputs.

Comment: unless edges is given sorted, for every algorithm that doesn't read all edges, one can find  a counter example with better MST, that needs an edge the algorithm didn't read.

Comment: Let me guess: the edge weights are Euclidean distances.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: I am afraid, i dont know what Euclidean distances are.

Comment: Euclidean distances are the distances between points in the canonical n-dimensional space. For 3 dimensions, the Euclidean distance between `(x,y,z)` and `(a,b,c)` would be `sqrt((x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2)`. Google helps.

Comment: okay, thanks for that. Then the weights are not euclidean distances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done in the sense that use an algo in time (m + nlogn)  which does not bear n^2 in all cases but it would best n^2 in most cases.